# valgrind reporting non-freed blocks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, memory-mapped-files

**Valgrind** leak file summary:

```
ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
malloc/free: in use at exit: 45,065 bytes in 12 blocks.
malloc/free: 161 allocs, 149 frees, 53,301 bytes allocated.
searching for pointers to 12 not-freed blocks.
checked 583,764 bytes.
```

One of this 12 blocks is from `strdup`. I should have freed things allocated by strdup, I agree.

My question is, in general, is it bad to leave non-freed blocks? Is it called *mem-leak* technically?

Are they not given back to the system once program dies?

Please advise.

**Edit 0:** Thanks for your responses. How can I know where are these 12 non-freed blocks? And what part of code is generating them?

Comment: Any modern OS will reclaim the memory when the program ends. But consider the program might someday grow up to become a daemon ... and never die. It's more difficult to find and remove memory leaks from a grown-up program than from a baby program :)

Comment: `--track-fds=yes` - was what I needed as an argument to valgrind. My prog was leaking them :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is given back to the system.

It it not technically a memory leak if you have a reference to the memory. To be a *memory leak* you must de-reference the memory.

```
void *str = malloc(10);
str = NULL;
```

It is bad to leave non-freed blocks at any point. If the program is finishing it, it might not be that bad, but it is not good for any future change you might do (e.g.: extract a function and call it multiple times).

Also, getting rid of all memory leaks will make it easier to track with valgrind any new (and relevant) one.

Comment: I love the double meaning of `de-reference`. (Think `x = *str;`.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is bad to leave non-freed blocks. It's called memory-leak. If you let it your program will eventually use all available memory in your system.
After program dies memory allocated by your program is freed.